# Unit Test passes in Visual Studio but fails on the command line (cant find Castle.Core)

Tags: nhibernate, msbuild, castle-windsor

I have a weird issue. My unit test passes in the IDE but fails in the command line (usually I'd expect it the other way around).

I'm using Visual Studio Team System 2008, and .net 3.5.

I have a 'soft' dependency in my project on NHibernate (NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll) and on Castle (Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll).

I've setup the testrunconfig file to add these DLLs as additional files to deploy under the Deployment tab.

In the IDE the test runs normally, but in the command line I get the error:

> Warning: Test Run deployment issue:
>   The assembly or module 'Castle.Core'
>   directly or indirectly referenced by
>   deployment item
>   'Dependencies\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll'
>   specified by the test run
>   configuration was not found.

I have no idea how to solve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm, wait, Castle.Core isn't in Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll ..., ignore this question if Castle.Core.dll is needed ...

Comment: Castle.Core.dll wasn't being included. Sigh. Nevermind about the Castle.Core error now. For some reason, the test still passes in one, fails in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No chance that you have either not copied it correctly (or forgot something to copy) to the deployment directory or not in the right place (folder, subfolder) when you run it from your command line?
Sounds like such an issue, also because the IDE most probably does this job implicitly.

Comment: Absolutely correct. In the end it turned out to be another project causing the confusion - thought I had a hard reference to my other project, whereas it was using Spring to inject the implementation and so had a soft reference. DOH